# How to store the node of an xml file in a string array and then to a structure in C++

Tags: c++, xml, string, struct

I have an xml file that looks like this :-

**Disp.xml:**

```
<Car>
<Car1>
    <Feature1>50</Feature1>
    <Feature2>100</Feature2>
    <Feature3>10</Feature3>
</Car1>
<Car2>
    <Feature1>100</Feature1>
    <Feature2>100</Feature2>
    <Feature3>10</Feature3>
</Car2>
<Car3>
    <Feature1>500</Feature1>
    <Feature2>0</Feature2>
    <Feature3>10</Feature3>
</Car3>
<Car4>
    <Feature1>1000</Feature1>
    <Feature2>0</Feature2>
    <Feature3>0</Feature3>
</Car4>
</Car>
```

**Code for Xml reading :-**

```
XmlDocument^ xDoc = gcnew XmlDocument();
String^ XPath =  ---path of file
xDoc->Load(XPath);
XmlNodeList^ nodes1 = xDoc->GetElementsByTagName("Car");
XmlNodeList^ car1 = xDoc->GetElementsByTagName("Car1");
XmlNodeList^ car1 = xDoc->GetElementsByTagName("Car2");
 for each (XmlNode^ node1 in nodes1)
 {          
    for each(XmlNode^ca1 in car1)
    {
        feature1= ca1->ChildNodes[1]->ChildNodes[0]->Value->ToString(); 
        feature2= ca1->ChildNodes[2]->ChildNodes[0]->Value->ToString(); 
        feature3= ca1->ChildNodes[3]->ChildNodes[0]->Value->ToString(); 
    }
}
```

I do have a structure

**Example :-**

```
struct Car1  
{
std::string feature1;
std::string feature2;
std::string feature3;
}
```

Similarly I have other structure too.

I need to read the nodes(values) of each car and store it in Car1,Car2,Car3,Car4 string array ,these string values must be later stored in individual structure in C++.

I have to do all this within a C++ Class Library .

A lot of research did let  me find out only read xml data but not to store in string array and later in individual structure and that too in C++.

Comment: When programming in C++, don't use `char*` for strings, use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: What goes wrong when you try that code?

Comment: @Kvothe : 1)I updated my code due to down vote, 2) I m confused as to how I must assign the node into a string array ;should they be considered as pointer to structure ??? or directly store them in their own structures....so that I can have minimal memory allocation

Comment: You're not assigning a pointer to the node to the structure, you're assigning the **value** of the node to the structure. Once the object handling reading the xml disappears the node will no longer exist and you would be left with a dangling pointer.

Comment: @Kvothe :Yes So you mean I shouldn't use pointer but just assign the values  to a string of array and passed it to the structure right??

Comment: I believe so. Like I said, I have no experience with .NET but that's the approach I'd take

Answer (score 0):

My favourite tool for reading XML in C++ http://pugixml.org/

Just read the values using that (or another) library and then save them to your struct

Comment: why there is a need for a tool ,cant I read them like my above code ,I just want them to be stored in a struct @Kvothe

Comment: That wasn't there when I posted this answer - I have no idea how that works, I haven't used .NET - you may want to add that tag to your question.