# How to declare multiple local variables as empty string of String^ in VC++

Tags: .net, string, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have many local variables 
for example : String a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10;

I need to declare them as empty string in String^ format.

If this string is in C#,
It is possible to assign them as below :-

```
string Camnr, Klantnr, Ordernr, Bonnr, Volgnr;// and so on.
Camnr = Klantnr = Ordernr = Bonnr = Volgnr = string.Empty;
```

But how should I declare them with String^ ???
If a single variable is there then the syntax would be

```
String^ a1= gcnew String(" ");
```

and if multiple variables declaration would be then like this :-

```
String^ a2= gcnew String(" ");
String^ a3= gcnew String(" ");
String^ a4= gcnew String(" ");
```

and so on.

This code will tend to look lengthy.Is there any better way to declare them?

Comment: isn't this c++cli and not c++

Comment: `gcnew String...` creates a new instance. It would be the same for any other object type. If you really want to create multiple instances, you HAVE to have multiple `gcnew`. You could do that in a loop (for, while...) and assign to an array.

Comment: @Amit :so the way I have posted with `gcnew` ,it would be like that one??

Comment: `String^ strings[10]; for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) strings[i] = gcnew String(" ");`

Comment: but what if the variable name needs to be different then because it needs to be assigned somewhere else too @Amit

Comment: You have to call `gcnew` multiple times. If you can't have that call in a single source code line (like in the `for` solution), you have to repeat this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't fundamentally different from C#:

```
  String ^a1, ^a2, ^a3, ^a4;
  a1 = a2 = a3 = a4 = String::Empty;
  // or 
  a1 = a2 = a3 = a4 = " ";
```

Do keep in mind that String is a reference type, there is no point in using `gcnew` for every single object reference.

Comment: is this feasible ,because gcnew creates a managed instance and returns a managed reference. – @Hans Passant

Comment: These are interned strings.  It is feasible.

Comment: I can execute my code as you have mentioned,a doubt exists will it automatically free the memory allocated in the end of my application@Hans Passant

Comment: These strings would be reading the value from an xml file  here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642452/how-to-store-the-node-of-an-xml-file-in-a-string-array-and-then-to-a-structure-i) The values stored once in these strings must be fixed one ..@Hans Passant

Comment: The garbage collector takes care of this automatically.  Nothing to do with "end of my application".  Stop helping.